# dwm.exe (Desktop Window-Manager) using enormous amounts of GPU

Tags: windows, graphics-card, gpu, windows-11, dwm

Lately, it appears very often that the Windows-Process called **Desktop Window Manager (dwm.exe)** uses up to 60% of my GPU (GPU0 - 3D). IT IS NOT a fake program nor a virus, I checked that.

I am using the latest version of *Windows 11* on an *Acer Aspire 5* and have an extending second monitor connected to my Laptop. The pre-installed graphics card is an *Intel Iris Xe*.

Of course, I looked the problem up on the internet, but that only gave various solutions for Windows 10 users.

I tried to:

1. System check
2. Update drivers
3. Reload GPU driver

But nothing worked. Is there anything I can do to solve this performance issue?

Comment: Question: What is your GPU? (1) If [HDR is enabled](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hdr-settings-in-windows-2d767185-38ec-7fdc-6f97-bbc6c5ef24e6), try to disable it.  (2) If you have NVIDIA, check in the NVIDIA Control Panel, Manage 3D Settings, Global Settings, if Power management mode is set to Optimal power (recommended). (3) Check the temperature of the CPU & GPU.

Comment: As I said in my post, I have an Intel Iris Xe GPU and I have HDR disabled. The temperatures are fine too.

Comment: @Aynos - Any solution for Windows 10 would likely work for Windows 11. Have you tried those suggestions? Does this problem happen in Safe Mode?

Comment: I tried everything I could find.

Comment: Try to kill dwm (it should re-spawn immediately). I would suggest also [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) and several anti-virus scans by more than one well-known product.

Comment: What @harrymc said, but just as a double-check, close all windowed processes too & see if any one is responsible.

Comment: I tested multiple programs, and it seems like any game that uses the GPU is causing dwm.exe to spike. I can't kill the process either because that would crash my system (Warning from task manager).

sfc /scannow causes an error (Windows Resource Protection could not complete the requested operation.) but I think that's another topic.

Answer (score 0):

> But nothing worked. Is there anything I can do to solve this performance issue?

Intel patched this issue with the release of their 30.0.101.1191 display drivers.  The issue you describe affected Intel's 6th generation through 10th generation processors.

> Stability improvements with Desktop Window Manager (DWM) on 6th
> generation Intel® Core™ Processors through 10th generation Intel®
> Core™ Processors

Source: [Release Notes (ReleaseNotes_101.1191.pdf)](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/691496/ReleaseNotes_101.1191.pdf)

Comment: I realize you indicated you attempted a driver update, but with this update being released on December 14th, 2021, and it matching your description exactly the chances of it not being applicable is very small. However, being unable to run SFC is a sign of system corruption, and would also explain the behavior.

Comment: I got a new PC for Christmas and the SSD was corrupted, I fixed that issue. I struggled a bit wile updating the driver, but it solved itself eventually. Graphics driver up to date: https://i.imgur.com/JVH45hy.png

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve the issue by restarting dwm process ignoring warning.

Whenever I plug in or out sceond screen or close the laptop lid with plug-in second screen, I always need restart dwm and everything be OK.

But I don't know why, just share my solution here. Hope it can help.